# How can I view log in ElasticSearch In Clearml?

Tags: devops, clearml

I followed the guide at  https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/deploying_clearml/clearml_server_linux_mac/ to deploy local server

I have implemented successfully

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FCwm.png)

Now, I want to check log elastic search and redis. How can I do that.

I can check log elasticsearch by docker logs container-id, but I think it's complicated for operating.

How can I do that.

Example, check log elastic search on kibana, I want something like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKlP5.png)